# Nested Union Statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, insert, union

I have 3 tables and wanted to get data from 2 tables and dump it to the third table. The two tables can have interlinked data and standalone data as well. So, I want to get the union of all 3 possible scenarios.

The 3 different tables are a, b and c

Sample Query:

```
Insert into c (scode, cname, fvalue, ISIN, nsymbol, paidup)

select scode, cname, fvalue, ISIN, null, null from a,b where a.ISIN <> b.ISIN

union

select scode, cname, fvalue, ISIN, nsymbol, paidup from a,b where a.ISIN = b.ISIN

union

select null, b.cname, b.fvalue, b.ISIN, b.nsymbol, b.paidup from a, b where b.ISIN <> a.ISIN
```

I get 3 rows inserted for each record, wherein I want only 1 record to be inserted. Any help will be appreciated.

I am looking for something like the below

Table A

scode cname fvalue ISIN

FB, Facebook, 10, INAB13230LL
IBM, International Business Machines, 10, INAB13230AB

Table B

nsymbol cname fvalue ISIN paidup

FBOOK, Facebook, 10 INAB13230LL, 10
MSFT, Microsoft, 10, INAB13230MS, 10

Table C

scode cname fvalue ISIN nsymbol paidup

FB, Facebook, 10, INAB13230LL, FBOOK, 10
IBM, International Business Machines, 10, INAB13230AB, NULL, NULL
Null, Microsoft, 10, INAB13230MS, MSFT, 10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would need to see some example data. However it would appear that you are returning 3 different rows for each item. Likely what you need is to determine which one you want to return. This might require having one subselect to get the record with the most importance, and then joining that against you current select to get the rest of the values

Comment: Table AFB, Facebook, 10, INAB13230LL                                      IBM, International Business Machines, 10, INAB13230ABFBOOK, 10 FBOOK, Facebook, 10 INAB13230LL, 10

Comment: I am looking for something like the below


Table A



scode cname fvalue ISIN



FB, Facebook, 10, INAB13230LL


IBM, International Business Machines, 10, INAB13230AB



Table B



nsymbol cname fvalue ISIN paidup



FBOOK, Facebook, 10 INAB13230LL, 10


MSFT, Microsoft, 10, INAB13230MS, 10



Table C



scode cname fvalue ISIN nsymbol paidup



FB, Facebook, 10, INAB13230LL, FBOOK, 10


IBM, International Business Machines, 10, INAB13230AB, NULL, NULL


Null, Microsoft, 10, INAB13230MS, MSFT, 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help. I would go out of the way to specify the table columns with dot notation to be sure of where things are from, and I would use exclusion JOINs as below:

```sql
select a.scode, a.cname, a.fvalue, a.ISIN, null, null from a left join b on a.ISIN = b.ISIN where b.ISIN IS NULL

union

select a.scode, a.cname, a.fvalue, a.ISIN, a.nsymbol, a.paidup from a inner join b on a.ISID = b.ISID

union

select null, b.cname, b.fvalue, b.ISIN, b.nsymbol, b.paidup from b left join a on b.ISIN = a.ISIN where a.ISIN IS NULL
```

Comment: Sorry... I didn't see a Accept button... I clicked the tick mark... I think thats what you meant right???